# Embedding C# List inside of another List

Tags: c#, list

What is the recommended way to essentially embed a List element within another List element?

For Example, here are snippets from my two data model classes so you can see what I'm trying to do:

```
class Person
{
   int Id;
   string LastName;
   string FirstName;
   List<SalesOrders> Orders;
}
```

and

```
class SalesOrders
{
    string OrderNumber;
    string CustomerPO;
    DateTime OrderDate;
}
```

Can this be done, and is it advisable or is there another method for doing this?

I need to be able to create a List element for a particular person, and then load their sales order data into their list element in the same method/routine.

Comment: I don't see a "list inside a list" anywhere in your sample nor in your description, but the class models shown here are pretty much normal and without too much surprise to me.

Comment: List can have a type of a class object, it seems logical to me that you place a property on your class Person of type List<SalesOrders>

Comment: You can have as many nested lists as you want. Nothing wrong with that

Comment: Indeed, nested Lists work. You can do this via a custom class like `Person` and then create a `List<Person>` Or you can use soemthing like `List<List<int>>` (a list of Integer lists)

Comment: The list inside of a list I thought was the "List<SalesOrders> Orders" in the Person class.  Wouldn't that create a List<> element of SAlesOrders for each Person instance created?  Or Does C# not handle lists like this when they are referenced within another list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A List in a list is something like this

```
List<List<SalesOrders>> personOrders;
```

In your case you have a list of objects of type Person which owns a property named Orders of type List and this is pretty standard.

In your code you will have your list of people and each of them will own their own list of orders.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely normal.

> I need to be able to create a List element for a particular person,
>   and then load their sales order data into their list element in the
>   same method/routine.

You can even do it in one line (not necessarily advisable, though). Something like the following:

```
void AddPerson(List<Person> listOfPeople, List<SalesOrders> salesOrdersList)
{
    listOfPeople.Add(new Person() { Orders = salesOrdersList });
}
```

This is only to give you an idea of how to do it. Obviously you would need more here, like setting the person's name etc.

(`SalesOrders` should probably be named `SalesOrder`.)